# Redirecting user after uploading a single document

Tags: 2013, event-receivers

I would like to redirect a user after uploading a document instead of letting them update the document's title.

So i want user never be able to see update document title form.

How can this done ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a custom permission to only give users "add" rights.  Then remove their "read" rights.  You could also set the default view to not show anything.

You might also have to add "read only" permissions to make it work.

Comment: I take back what I said about permissions.  If you take away read rights, they can't see the list or library at all.  My apologies.

Comment: That is the best answer ever, I would had never thought it, even though user group has full permissions on the site, when I added "read only" to them, it fixed the issue. Excellent, saved me hours and hours...

Comment: i am sorry but it actually do not work, i tested it again this morning and there is no sign of life in the provided solution :( i will keep looking